# Why does GROUP_CONCAT make my query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a rather large MySQL table that I'm searching for duplicates on. I'm finding exact matches of email addresses by doing something like:

```
SELECT email FROM customers WHERE email != '' GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds to run.

However, if I add a GROUP_CONCAT to the select query it speeds it up to only about half a second. For example, both of these run in about half a second:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), email FROM customers WHERE email != '' GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM customers WHERE email != '' GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Can anyone explain why adding in GROUP_CONCAT, which makes it return MORE data, speeds up the query?

When I do an EXPLAIN on both queries, the version without the GROUP_CONCAT says "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" while the version with GROUP_CONCAT says "Using where; Using filesort"

So I guess adding GROUP_CONCAT makes it not use a temporary table and that speeds it up? Is there any way around this? Because all I really want is a list of the email addresses so I can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email IN ([above query]);
```

I've created a mock schema and data to see the difference at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aTPCPEjy5mp1EgLuvTjaUr/2

Details:
Running MySQL 5.6.36
Customers table I'm actually working with has 126,633 records with 113,053 distinct email records. 4,730 of these emails are empty.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide a table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers`, example data, expected results and the post the output's of the `EXPLAIN` in the post so we can verify.. Also posting a MySQL version might be handy `SELECT VERSION()` because of Optimizer changes between MySQL versions.

Comment: Also post results from `select count(*) from customers`, `select count(distinct email) from customers` and `select count(*) from customers where email = ''`.

Comment: You have run the `GROUP_CONCAT` queries after the simple query and they were faster. Have you tried running the simple query after the `GROUP_CONCAT` queries? It may be that data gets cached and doesn't have to be read from disk with the second query. (I.e. whichever query runs first is slow and the following queries are fast.)

Comment: I've updated my question with all of the details all of you asked for.
@ThorstenKettner, no, I've verified that this is not due to being in memory or anything and see consistent results no matter what order I run the queries in.

Comment: It's faster because it's using a different plan. You should ask "why does it use a temporary table in the first case but not the second".

Comment: @RLHawk did you just upload your customer's PII to db-fiddle?

Comment: I can verfy the difference in execution time on *MariaDB 10.0.19* - And though I'm also curious, I would just change email data type to varchar(191) and add an index on it. Then all queries run at least 10 times faster.

Comment: @Ben This is definitely not real date. This is fake generated data. This isn't even our table schema but shows my point none the less.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in understanding the "why" behind this than an exact solution for my specific schema. I'll be running similar queries on phone numbers, names, street addresses, etc. and this is purely for one non-primary function within our larger application so adding indexes to several columns isn't a good option in this specific scenario. Just wanted to learn why it is this way so I can learn more and optimize my queries accordingly.

Comment: MySQL's optimizer is far from perfect. You seem to have stumbled upon a situation where it chooses a suboptimal execution plan. This shouldn't lead to you writing strange queries (like adding `AND GROUP_CONCAT(id) IS NOT NULL` to each and every `HAVING` clause). Don't "optimize" your queries when not running into performance issues. Such optimizations may easily backfire in a  later MySQL version when they fix the optimizer flaw. Now that Paul Spiegel confirms the issue (albeit in MariaDB), you may want to file this as a bug in MySQL, so they know about this and can work on it.

Comment: Reproduced on MySQL 5.6.34, 5.5.57, MariaDB 10.1.37, 10.2.12, 10.3.13. For latest MariaDB the difference is less than 50% (450ms to 350ms). On MySQL 5.1.49 - no difference in ex. time. Couldn't test MySQL 8 yet.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for some pair with a noticeable difference.